# Craft CMS 3 - Entries field, getURL

Tags: entries, craft3

Just migrating a site from 2 to 3 and stuck on this little call, cannot find anything in the docs at all.

Matrix field, Entries.

```
<a href="{{ entry.featuredProjectLink.getUrl() }}">
```

Cannot for the life of me find the equivalent/new way in the docs.

TIA

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`entry.featuredProjectLink` is not an element or an array of elements, it is an object of type `MatrixQuery` in order to fetch elements you have to use the `.one()` or `.all()` function

```
<a href="{{ entry.featuredProjectLink.one().getUrl() }}">
```

[Element Queries](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/element-queries.html)

[Relations](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/relations.html#the-relatedto-parameter) -> the "Going Through Matrix" part is the thing you want

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. No link is being rendered however. Double checked, made sure the Entries field was completed, and yes, many times in the actual entry. Bizarre.

Comment: is your `featuredProjectLink` a field of type Matrix? if so you won't receive a url because matrix blocks don't have an URL. You need to either select a field of type `Categories, Entries, Assets` or a field inside your matrix

Comment: It is and I am now sorted, thank you very much. Cleared the heavy caching I had set up.